# If I have a generic GPRS device and a GPRS server setup, do I need to pay for any gsm/gprs data provider?

Tags: gsm, gprs

Please forgive my ignorance.

A client of mine is looking for to have a gps device with GPRS capabilities send updates every little while to a gprs server which he has. Since it's my understanding GPRS uses GSM, won't a subscription to a data service be necessary?

Again, please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: What is a GPRS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, he will need a subscription to a network operator, and a SIM card for each modem.  You're correct, GPRS is a data enhancement to the GSM network.